# SSH won't ask for 2FA code

Tags: ssh, debian, google-authenticator

I'm trying to confiugre SSH 2FA on a Debian 11 server with Google Authenticator.

I have password login disabled,only publickey-login is allowed.

I already followed [this](https://4sysops.com/archives/enable-two-factor-authentication-for-ssh-in-linux/) and [this](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/secure-ssh-access-with-2fa/?ref=linuxhandbook.com) guide, but without success.

The fact is, that when I try to connect to my server, it doesn't ask for the 2fa code, but just for the public key's password.

I also found out that, for some reasons, when I put `AuthenticatioMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive`in `/etc/ssh/sshd_confing`, `keyboard-interactive` acts like `password`, and asks for the user's password instead of Google Authenticator code.
Here's my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
Port 5566
MaxAuthTries 3
MaxSessions 2
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
UsePAM yes
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive
```

And here's my `/etc/pam.d/sshd`

```
# Standard Un*x password updating.
#@include common-password
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
```

This is `ssh -v` output:

```
lc@lc-ThinkPad-E550:~$ ssh -v -p 5566 lc@192.168.43.240
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.7, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.43.240 [192.168.43.240] port 5566.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/lc/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/lc/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/lc/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/lc/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/lc/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/lc/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/lc/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/lc/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/lc/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/lc/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/lc/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/lc/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/lc/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/lc/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.43.240:5566 as 'lc'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:V6k3rMQPjUN0z/IHqIGQLcu+qwcxUnG7t7UBNgVICdk
debug1: checking without port identifier
debug1: Host '192.168.43.240' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/lc/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: found matching key w/out port
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/lc/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:g7Mg0E/en4eCckxoHso4aeJTNUrBrciEml+UEhc2kSE
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/lc/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/lc/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/lc/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/lc/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/lc/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/lc/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/lc/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:g7Mg0E/en4eCckxoHso4aeJTNUrBrciEml+UEhc2kSE
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/lc/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:g7Mg0E/en4eCckxoHso4aeJTNUrBrciEml+UEhc2kSE
Enter passphrase for key '/home/lc/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Authenticated with partial success.
debug1: Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Password:
```

That "Password" is where I'm stuck.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you have followed all steps? I can see discrepancy between your config and docs which you are following.